# uWSGI --http :80 doesn't listen IPv6 interface

Tags: http, python-3.x, ipv6, uwsgi

Why doesn't uWSGI listen on IPv6 interface, even if system is 100% IPv6 ready? As far as I could see there aren't parameters nor documentation covering this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your INI config file specify something like this

[uwsgi]

socket = **[::]**:your_port_number

Or from the CL,

./uwsgi -s **[::]**:your_port_number

The server shall now listen along all the interfaces (including IPv4, if the underlying OS supports dual stack TCP sockets)